# Linux script throwing error though it completely looks fine

Tags: linux

I have to write Linux script for below question

```
Write a script that renames files based on the file extension.  The script should prompt the user  for a file extension.  
Next, it should ask the user what prefix to prepend to the file name(s).  By  default the prefix should be the current date in YYYY­MM­DD format.  
So, if the user simply  presses enter the date will be used.  Otherwise, whatever the user entered will be used as the  prefix.  
Next, it should display the original file name and the new name of the file.  Finally, it  should rename the file.
```

I wrote below shell script & its throwing error. To me script looks completely fine. Though I am able to write alternative script but Could someone please suggest reason & resolution of error in this script.

**Script:**

```
#!/bin/bash    
read -p "Please enter a file extension : " EXT
for f in *.${EXT}
do
read -p "Please enter a file prefix (Press ENTER to prefix current Date) :" PREFIX
if [ -z "PREFIX" ]
then
  new = "$(date +"%Y-%M-%d")-$(basename ${f})"
  mv $f $new
  echo "$f renamed to $new"
else
   new = "${PREFIX}-${f}"
   mv $f $new
  echo "$f renamed to $new"   
fi
done
```

**Error :**

```
./new.sh: line 13: new: command not found
BusyBox v1.24.2 (2017-05-25 17:33:59 CEST) multi-call binary.

Usage: mv [-fin] SOURCE DEST
or: mv [-fin] SOURCE... DIRECTORY

Rename SOURCE to DEST, or move SOURCE(s) to DIRECTORY

        -f      Don't prompt before overwriting
        -i      Interactive, prompt before overwrite
        -n      Don't overwrite an existing file
*.png renamed to

[root@localhost ~]#
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spaces are spoiling your script during assignment

```
#new = "$(date +"%Y-%M-%d")-$(basename ${f})"
new="$(date +"%Y-%M-%d")-$(basename ${f})"
```

also

```
#new = "${PREFIX}-${f}"
new="${PREFIX}-${f}"
```

[shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) is an excellent tool for a basic shell checking

Comment: Also line should be modified as below :
#if [ -z "PREFIX" ] to
if [ -z "$PREFIX" ]


#$(date +"%Y-%M-%d") to
(date +"%Y-%m-%d")